# Surjective quadratic mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quadratic-forms

Are there any known values of $n$ for which there exists a surjective quadratic mapping $Q:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with non-trivial zeroes?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but $(x^2 - y^2, 2xy)$ is surjective for $n=2$

Comment: By "non-trivial zeroes" do you mean a non-zero $n$-vector that is mapped to the zero vector?

Comment: yes, precisely that.